# Reordering data in JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json

Consider this Javascript object and code:

Javascript Object

```
{
    "thing":{
       "data":"some data",
       "thumb":"some data",
       "data1":"some data",
       "data2":"some data",
       "data3":"some data",
    },
    "extra1":[
       {
          "extradata1":"some data",
          "extradata2":"some data",
          "extradata3":"some data",
          "extradata4":"some data"
       },
       {
          "extradata1":"some data",
          "extradata2":"some data",
          "extradata3":"some data",
          "extradata4":"some data"
       }
    ],
    "extra2":[
       {
          "hightlighted": false, 
          "extradata2":"some data",
       },
       {
          "hightlighted": false, 
          "extradata2":"some data",
       },
       {
          "hightlighted": true, 
          "extradata2":"some data",
       },
       {
          "hightlighted": false, 
          "extradata2":"some data",
       }
     ]
}
```

I want to find an object in 'extra2' based on if a value is true or not, remove it and add it back into the same json object but at the top of the 'extra2' object.

Currently my thinking is this:

```
for (var i=0; i<object.extra2.length; i++){
        if (object.extra2[i].highlighted === true) {
            highlightStore = object.extra2[i];
            delete object.extra2[i]
            object.extra2.push(highlightStore)
        }
    }
```

However I can't seem to get this to work

Comment: Is there any specific reason why ordering matters? JSON, as far as I know, is rather angoistic on the data order. Also, extra2 is an array, not an object

Comment: its being delivered by an api and i want to order it correctly in the front end based on a flag that is given in each object.

Comment: its an array of objects yes

Comment: Those are not "JSON objects". They're JavaScript objects. JSON is a serialization scheme. Anyway JavaScript object properties have an ordering controlled by the runtime, but you can't control that in any direct way. Reliance on property ordering is a seriously bug-prone idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't mutate the original data, that's always a bad idea, so you don't want to use mutating methods like `push`, `shift` etc.

Create new variables to hold partial and/or transformed copies of the original instead.

In your particular case, you could do:

```js
const extra2sorted = [ ...data.extra2.filter(v => v.hightlighted), ...data.extra2.filter(v => !v.hightlighted) ]
```

Comment: wow! this is what i wanted to do, but i don't understand exactly what is happening here.. I've seen the ... syntax mentioned in the svelte documentation before, I'm also not fully understanding what is happening with the v.highlighted part.. if you have some time to explain that would be great.. either way many thanks!

Comment: The `...` syntax is not specific to Svelte at all, it is part of Javascript and is better known as the Spread syntax (and its related cousin the Rest syntax). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax for a more in-depth explanation. The `Array.filter` method filters an array according to a given predicate, which evaluates to `true` (the element evaluated is preserved) or `false` (the element is rejected).

Comment: So what we're doing here is concatenating two filtered arrays: in the first one all elements have the `hightlighted` property set to true (hence the filter predicate for element `v` is `v.hightlighted`) and in the second (which is the complement of the first) all elements have the `hightlighted` property set to false (hence the filter predicate for element `v` is `!v.hightlighted` - which evaluates to true if `hightlighted` is false). In the end, it's just a quick way to sort your array based on a boolean property.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here:

```
object.extra2.push(highlightStore)
```

The array [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method adds one or more elements to the end of an array, but as you need to add the item at the top you simply need to use the array [`unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) method like:

```
object.extra2.unshift(highlightStore)
```

As the `unshift()` method adds one or more elements to the beginning of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to sort the data in question, using the `"hightlighted"` property. (Notice the misspelling.  This presumably should be `"highlighted"`.)  That might look like this:

```js
const object = {thing: {data: "some data", thumb: "some data", data1: "some data", data2: "some data", data3: "some data"}, extra1: [{extradata1: "some data", extradata2: "some data", extradata3: "some data", extradata4: "some data"}, {extradata1: "some data", extradata2: "some data", extradata3: "some data", extradata4: "some data"}], extra2: [{hightlighted: false, extradata2: "some data"}, {hightlighted: false, extradata2: "some data"}, {hightlighted: true, extradata2: "some data"}, {hightlighted: false, extradata2: "some data"}]}

object .extra2 .sort (({hightlighted: h1}, {hightlighted: h2}) =>
  (h1 && !h2) ? -1 : (h2 && ! h1) ? 1 : 0
)

console .log (object)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```